# Uncaught TypeError: closeBtn.addEventListener is not a function at script.js:8

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having some trouble with adding the function in my closeBtn because it returns the error Uncaught TypeError: closeBtn.addEventListener is not a function

I really don't know why other variable is working fine, I don't think it's a typo error I double check the class name I call..here's the java script

```
   //View Faculty Schedule MODAL SCRIPT//
var modal2 = document.getElementById('view-modal'); //Get Modal Element
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('searchfaculty'); //Button Element
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn'); //Close Button Element
//opening
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
//closing
closeBtn.addEventListener();

function openModal() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

then the html

```
<div id="view-modal" class="modal2">
<div class="modal-view">
    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
    <p>sfsdfsdfsdfdf</p>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Check what `getElementsByClassName()` returns. It's a NodeList... Try `getElementsByClassName()[0]` instead.

Comment: @marekful and then `closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);`

Comment: The point is `closeBtn` is not a ref to an HTMLElement instance as you expect (`modalBtn` is however), but to a NodeList containing one or more elements.

Comment: @marekful Does not really matter here, but it's a  `HTMLCollection`, actually.

Comment: Correct. Used to return NodeList in earlier implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning node list collection in array so you have to get by index.

```
closeBtn[0].addEventListener(function(){
 });
```

[see how to choose correct selector](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-avoid-frustration-by-choosing-the-right-javascript-selector-73c64c3906b6)

Comment: it works, thanks..can you please tell me why I need to point out the zero? in closeBtn sir?

Comment: closeBtn is class so you could use many places where you need. So JavaScript identify all those elements and return back as collection of node list.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` returns the first HTML element with corresponding id whereas `getElementsByClassName()` returns HTML collection of all elements having corresponding class.

```js
 closeBtn[0].addEventListener('click',()=>{
 //execute your code
 });
```

```js
var modal2 = document.getElementById("view-modal"); //Get Modal Element
//var modalBtn = document.getElementById("searchfaculty"); //Button Element
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn"); //Close Button Element
//Your answer
closeBtn[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
  //execute your function
});
//check what it returns
console.log(modal2);
console.log(closeBtn);
function openModal() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

        <div id="view-modal" class="modal2">
            <div class="modal-view">
                <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <p>1st Close Button</p>
        </div>
        <div id="view-modal" class="modal2">
            <div class="modal-view">
                        <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
                    <p>2nd Close Button </p>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

[For better understanding you can refer to this code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/xr8plv16lp)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for taking the time to provide a runnable sample! I think your answer would be even better if you used Stack Overflow's *own* snippet feature. It's the file icon with `</>` in it in the toolbar when you [edit] your post.